# Is it possible to change firefox bidi numeral by javascript?

Tags: javascript, firefox, config

Is it possible to change firefox [bidi](http://kb.mozillazine.org/About%3aconfig_entries#Bidi.) numeral by javascript? I need it to display numbers in a report created by PHP.

Answer (score 1):

From a normal web page, no.

Here is an old article about saving an html file in the mozilla RES folder that may still work

http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=87755

Make a file in your Firefox installation folder, under the res directory, called for example 'bidi.htm',

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
                      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
   <title>Bidi Toggle</title>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   // <![CDATA[
   function loaded() {
      netscape.security.PrivilegeManager
      .enablePrivilege("UniversalBrowserAccess UniversalXPConnect");
      var prefs = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/preferences-service;1"]
                  .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIPrefBranch);
      if (prefs.getIntPref("bidi.numeral") == 3) {
         prefs.setIntPref("bidi.numeral", 4);
      }
      else {
         prefs.setIntPref("bidi.numeral", 3);
      }
      self.close();
   };
   self.onload = loaded;   
   // ]]>
   </script>
</head>
<body>
   Please wait...
</body>
</html>
```

and have a bookmarklet 
`javascript: void(window.open('resource:///res/bidi.htm'));`

Comment: tnx mplungjan.changing direction of page is not what I need,I need to change the display of numbers from English to Persian.

Comment: I understand. I have looked if I could find something. There used to be several bugs in Fx pertaining to the bidi.numeral setting. I do not know if it was fixed. Can you try the script on the link I gave you?

Comment: Thank you so much,but the report is accessed from different PCs,so I need a global approach that doesn't need to create a file on hard disk.

Comment: I suggest you generate the numbers on the server using GD